# Python 3: for a class type, what happens when in is called?

Tags: python-3.x

If I have a class with __getitem__ defined,

```
c = MyClass()
x in c
```

appears to iteratively call c.__getitem__ with all values y, 0 <= y <= x. And

```
[x for x in c]
```

appears to iteratively call c.__getitem__ with all positive ints.

Is there a better way to overload `in` on a class type?

Comment: If you're going to write a class like this, I would recommend inheriting from one of the classes in [`collections.abc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html).  It may save you a fair amount of typing and can help ensure your class is duck-type compatible with `list`/`dict`/`set` or whatever you're trying to emulate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python gives priority to `__contains__()` for membership test operators. So, a better approach is to override `__contains__()` method.

From [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__)

> For objects that don’t define `__contains__()`, the membership test
>   first tries iteration via `__iter__()`, then the old sequence iteration
>   protocol via `__getitem__()`

Answer (score 1):

you should define a

```
 __contains__()
```

method